# Using if for multiple input lists in Python list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

How do you use an if statement in a list comprehension when there are multiple input lists.  Here is the code that I'm using and the error that I'm getting:

(I get that it's not able to apply modulus to a list, but not sure how to specifically reference the x in each of the lists as it iterates through them)

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]

nums = [x**2 for x in (a,b) if x%2==0]
print(nums)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a cause with the `if` statement, the issue here is with `x in (a, b)`. When that executes, `x` takes on a `list` value (first `a`, then `b`) and then Python will try try to execute your `if` condition on it, an expression of the form:

```
[1, 2, 3] % 2
```

is done, which obviously isn't allowed.

Instead, use [`chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) from [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) to chain both lists together and make `x` take values from them:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]

nums = [x**2 for x in chain(a,b) if x%2==0]
print(nums)
[4, 16, 36]
```

If you're using Python `>= 3.5` you could also unpack in the list literal `[]`:

```
nums = [x**2 for x in [*a, *b] if x%2==0]
```

Answer (score 1):

As Jim said, you are `mod` a list to a `int`.

You can also use `+`, e.g., `nums = [x**2 for x in a+b if x%2==0]`.